# How to discretize using cut pandas?

Tags: pandas, cut

I have a column called SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE (hours in format of 24 hours) (example: 1140 = 11:40)
however there area several numbers with tens greater than 59.

I inserted the following code, but the the classification is wrong:

```html
df_horario = pd.DataFrame({'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE': np.random.randint(1, 2359,20)})

df_horario['Horario'] = pd.cut(x=df['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'], bins=[1, 159, 359, 559, 759, 959, 1159, 1359, 1559, 1759, 1959, 2159, 2359],
labels=['1 to 2', '2 to 4', '4 to 6','6 to 8', '8 to 10', '10 to 12','12 to 14', '14 to 16', '16 to 18', '18 to 20', '20 to 22', '22 to 23'])
print(df_horario)
```

The result is wrong, what am I doing wrong?:

```js
SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE   Horario
0                  1496    1 to 2
1                   493    1 to 2
2                   291    1 to 2
3                  1972    1 to 2
4                   229    2 to 4
5                  1208    4 to 6
6                    86    6 to 8
7                  1599  10 to 12
8                  1620  12 to 14
9                  2322  14 to 16
10                 1650  14 to 16
11                  507  16 to 18
12                  405  16 to 18
13                 1067  18 to 20
14                  904  20 to 22
15                  520    1 to 2
16                 2044    1 to 2
17                 1018    1 to 2
18                 1143    1 to 2
19                 1161    1 to 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_horario = pd.DataFrame({'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE': np.random.randint(1, 2359,20)})
```

convert to bins

```
labels=['1 to 2', '2 to 4', '4 to 6','6 to 8', '8 to 10', '10 to 12','12 to 14', '14 to 16', '16 to 18', '18 to 20', '20 to 22', '22 to 23']
df_horario['Horario'] = pd.cut(x=df_horario['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'], bins=[1, 159, 359, 559, 759, 959, 1159, 1359, 1559, 1759, 1959, 2159, 2359], labels=labels)
```

output

```
    SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE   Horario
0                  1278  12 to 14
1                  1479  14 to 16
2                  2249  22 to 23
3                  1419  14 to 16
4                   681    6 to 8
5                  1863  18 to 20
6                  1605  16 to 18
7                  2248  22 to 23
8                  1804  18 to 20
9                  2054  20 to 22
10                 2095  20 to 22
11                  750    6 to 8
12                 2203  22 to 23
13                 1248  12 to 14
14                 1436  14 to 16
15                 1051  10 to 12
16                 1383  14 to 16
17                  787   8 to 10
18                  853   8 to 10
19                 1504  14 to 16
```